# Getting the index of multiple selected items in a listbox

Tags: c#, wpf

У меня есть Listbox c режимом выбора Multiple.
Проблема заключается в том, что при выборе нескольких элементов с одинаковым значением, я получаю результат то, что у них одинаковый индекс, как показано рис.2. А при выборе элемента с другим значением получаю результат, как на рис.3;
Как можно решить эту проблему?

```
private void btn_1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string values = null;
        foreach (var catgry in ListBox_Answers.SelectedItems)
        {
            values += ListBox_Answers.Items.IndexOf(catgry).ToString() + "";

        }
        MessageBox.Show(values);
    }

    private void btn_2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ListBox_Answers.Items.Add(txt_Value.Text);
        ListBox_Answers.Items.Refresh();
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это потому что вы используете IndexOf. А какая у вас вообще задача? Что вы пытаетесь сделать? Размещайте в ListBox не просто числа, а создайте класс и размещайте его экземпляры

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это довольно сложно, т. к. `ListBox` работает не с массивом индексов. Вопрос 1: зачем вам индекс? Ну да ладно:

```cs
public class ListItem
{
    public int Index { get; }
    public object Value { get; }

    // ...
}
```

Здесь идёт равенство по ссылке, т. е. даже если у 2-х объектов данного класса будет одинаковый индекс и значение, то они всё равно не равны (да, потому что у объекта типа `string` есть оператор `==` все объекты с одинаковым содержанием возвращают одинаковый индекс). Именно вот эти объекты нужно добавлять в `ListBox`:

```cs
void btnShow_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    StringBuilder indices = new StringBuilder(answers.SelectedItems.Count);

    foreach (var answer in answers.SelectedItems)
        indices.Append(((ListItem)answer).Index.ToString()[^1]);

    MessageBox.Show(indices);
}
void btnAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    answers.Items.Add(new ListItem(
        index: answers.SelectedItems.Count,
        value: txtValue.Text));
    answers.Items.Refresh();
}
```